# Combining Map with Drop

Tags: list-manipulation

I assume my question has been answered before, but I can't find such an answer anywhere:.

How can I drop the first element from each sublist within a list? I should be able to use

```
Map[Drop, list,2]
```

right? But how could I give `Drop` the arguments it needs from within Map?

Comment: You can simply use [`Rest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rest.html) instead: `Rest /@ list`

Comment: Thanks - but for my future sanity: Can functions like Drop[] that require the list as their first argument even be used with Map[]?

Comment: You could also use `Drop[list, None, 1]`.

Comment: You can find a lot of examples on how to use functions with multiple arguments inside `Map` in the [documentation for `Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html),  the [Pure Functions tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html), and the [Function (&) documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html).

Answer (score 2):

Prepare some data

```
data=Permutations[Range[3]]
(*{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}*)
```

Drop first element of each list

```
Map[Drop[#, 1] &, data]
(*{{2, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}*)
```

Of course `Rest` as suggested by @Karsten is even shorter.